# Yii2: GridView: Search foreign field with data from hasMany

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, foreign-keys

I need to be able to search from a GridView based on a related foreign attribute.

I have two tables with a relation:

```
operators (id, name, country)
platforms (id, operator_id, platform)
```

Many platforms can belong to one operator.

What I have managed so far is when I search for platform (name), to list the operators that have that platform, but still, in the GridView I get all the platforms of that operator. I need only the ones that match to be displayed:

```
Search for "windows" in Platforms

Name    Country      Platforms
=======================================
Oper1   Egypt        linux1, windows3, windows4
Oper5   Germany      Mac, windows2, Mac-b
```

I want the ones that do not match to not be listed at all in Platforms.

This is the getPlatforms from Operators model:

```
public function getPlatforms()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Platforms::className(), ['operator_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I guess I need to limit the results here, but How do I access platforms search text here?

GridView from the view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table table-condensed'],
    'columns' => [
        #['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        #'id',
        'abbr',
        'name',
        'country',
        [
            'attribute' => 'platforms',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {

                // RETURN A COMMA LIST OF THE PLATFORMS

                return $this->render('_platformsInline', [
                    'model' => $model->platforms,
                ]);
            }
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

The search function of OperatorsSearch:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Operators::find();

    $query->joinWith(['platforms']);
    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        // 'platforms.platform' => $this->platforms,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'abbr', $this->abbr])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'platforms.platform', $this->platforms]);

    // var_dump($query->createCommand()->rawSql);
    // exit;
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

**EDIT:**

So here's a bit more insight at what's going on in the background (pouring my notes here while I try to figure this out).

These are (the most important) queries that take place in the database when I render() with the current code:

```
35 Query    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `operators` LEFT JOIN `platforms` ON `operators`.`id` = `platforms`.`operator_id` WHERE `platforms`.`platform` LIKE '%windows%'

    This one returns:
    +----------+
    | COUNT(*) |
    +----------+
    |        4 |
    +----------+

35 Query    SELECT `operators`.* FROM `operators` LEFT JOIN `platforms` ON `operators`.`id` = `platforms`.`operator_id` WHERE `platforms`.`platform` LIKE '%windows%' ORDER BY `abbr` LIMIT 20

    (Note the duplicate returned results)
    +----+-------+-----------------+---------+
    | id | abbr  | name            | country |
    +----+-------+-----------------+---------+
    | 39 | HP-KW | Hewlett Packard | Kuwait  |
    | 43 | DL-DZ | Dell            | Algeria |
    | 43 | DL-DZ | Dell            | Algeria |
    | 43 | DL-DZ | Dell            | Algeria |
    +----+-------+-----------------+---------+

35 Query    SELECT * FROM `platforms` WHERE `operator_id` IN (39, 43)

    (And here we take all the platforms based on the match above)
    +-----+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+
    | id  | operator_id | platform                  | plat_status |
    +-----+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+
    |  50 |          39 | Linux2                    |           1 |
    |  65 |          39 | Mac1                      |           1 |
    |  85 |          39 | Mac2                      |           0 |
    | 102 |          39 | Windows1                  |           0 |
    | 124 |          39 | Linux3                    |           0 |
    |  33 |          43 | Linux with gadgets        |           0 |
    |  62 |          43 | Virtual windows plat      |           0 |
    |  77 |          43 | Mac1                      |           0 |
    |  90 |          43 | Mac2                      |           0 |
    |  91 |          43 | MM                        |           0 |
    | 110 |          43 | MM2                       |           0 |
    | 126 |          43 | Windows on VM             |           0 |
    | 127 |          43 | Windows2 on VM            |           0 |
    +-----+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+
```

I think I'm approaching this at a totally wrong angle at this point.

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
return $this->render('_platformsInline', [
                    'model' => $model->getPlatforms()->andWhere('like','platform', $searchModel->platforms)->all(),
                ]);
```

In that way you are accesing to the ActiveQuery with the getPlatforms() method for the relation, adding a where clause to only get the ones that fulfill the criteria given by OperatorsSearch->platforms.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery

Comment: `$searchModel` is not in that scope, so apparently I cannot use it there...

Answer (score 0):

What i understood so far that you are able to search properly but you want those platforms to be hidden that is not searched currently even if the operator has that platform assigned to him.

```
Default Operators Lists

Name    Country      Platforms
=======================================
Oper1   Egypt        linux1, windows3, windows4
Oper5   Germany      Mac, windows2, Mac-b
```

Search for `"windows"` in Platforms filter input the output should be like below

```
Name    Country      Platforms
=======================================
Oper1   Egypt        windows3, windows4
Oper5   Germany      windows2,
```

Maybe there is any other way to do that but one of the ways is to look for the `$_GET` i.e `Yii::$app->request->get()` as it would have the value that you searched for and you can use to compare.

I assume that you have a custom attribute defined with the name `platforms` inside your `OperatorsSearch` model and have added it to the `safe` rules too.

I am not sure why you need a view to render the comma separated values but since it wasn't added I would post the solution without view you can adjust it according to your needs, change your column configurations to the following

```
[
    'attribute' => 'platforms' ,
    'format' => 'raw' ,
    'value' => function ($model) {
     $html='';        

     foreach ( $model->platforms as $platform ) {
        if ( isset ( Yii::$app->request->get ( 'OperatorsSearch' )['my_platforms'] ) && Yii::$app->request->get ( 'OperatorsSearch' )['my_platforms'] !== '' ) {
            $html .= (strpos ( $platform->platform , Yii::$app->request->get ( 'OperatorsSearch' )['my_platforms'] ) === FALSE) ? '' : $platform->platform . ',';
        } else {
            $html .= $platform->platform . ',';
        }
     }
        return $html;
    }
] ,
```

Comment: First of all, this would probably work.

As you might guess though, I'm pretty new to Yii2 and I'm trying to get the hang of it by doing things the "right" way. So, I guess there probably ~is~ a way to limit the results in the model side of the project. Thing is I totally get lost with all the different scopes and all the layers I still have no idea how they are interconnected.